# Can you disable all css loading on chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am looking for an option based solution.
Of course there is an option to remove all style tags one by one from the elements panel, this will not remove inline injected styles.

For debugging purposes I would like this option to be at reach, I remember this being an option at one time.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you could try commenting out link tag in html body that has link to CSS stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on Firefox, found in the menu under `View -> Website Style -> No Style` (the wording might be slightly different, I don't have english version of FF installed but you should find it rather easily I guess.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked, which is how to disable CSS in **Chrome**.

Comment: That's why I kept the answer short and also put this early on in my answer. If they can switch to FF this might help them and debug in FF. If it's a strict chrome-only environment then they can stop reading the question and not waste any time.